# Adding life sprites in SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am building my first swift game and i am having difficulties implementing the life for the player. it should display three lives in different screen positions, like a miniature image... i am aware that a for loop can do the job, but i am not sure how to write it. When i try to add the same sprite to the screen with the addChild(LifeIndex) it throws an error.

here is the following code:

```
  // Add Life to player

    let lifeIndex = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")

    var lifeCount = 3

    lifeIndex.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * -1.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)

    let lifeIndexMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.1), duration: NSTimeInterval(0.7))

    let lifeIndexRotation = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-2 * M_PI), duration: 0.3)

    addChild(lifeIndex)

    lifeIndex.runAction(SKAction.sequence([lifeIndexMove, lifeIndexRotation]))
```

How can i do this three times? Also, i need different points into the moveTo, so they can be side by side, and not on top of each other.

Comment: put all of that in a for loop that loops lifeCount number of times.  Will lifeIndexMove and lifeIndexRotation going to be the same for all three?

Comment: lifeIndexRotation is going to be the same, but i need an increment in the x parameter of the lifeIndexMove so it can be side by side with the others sprites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    // Add Life to player

    var lifeIndexCount = 0
    var positionAdd:CGFloat = 10.0

    for lifeIndexCount in 0..<3 {

        let lifeIndex = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")

        lifeIndex.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * -1.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)

        let lifeIndexMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: (size.width * 0.1) + positionAdd, y: size.height * 0.1), duration: NSTimeInterval(0.7))

        let lifeIndexRotation = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-2 * M_PI), duration: 0.3)

        lifeIndex.runAction(SKAction.sequence([lifeIndexMove, lifeIndexRotation]))

        addChild(lifeIndex)

        positionAdd = positionAdd + 30.0

    }
```

Comment: It gets little compilation errors but are simple to solve. Biggest problem is on the addChild(lifeIndex) that throws an error.

Comment: updated code try moving var lifeIndex = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")  inside the loop.  If that doesn't work I will delete the answer until I can properly test my suggested answer

Comment: same compilation errors and lifeIndex needs to be a let type, but yea, solved the main problem that was a crash into addChild method. Thanks!

Comment: will you update the syntax errors in the answer for completeness.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you simply create three `nodes` and Position the first one like this:

```
lifeIndex.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * -1.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)
```

the second one

```
lifeIndex2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * -1.5 + lifeIndex2.size.width * 1.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)
```

and the third

```
lifeIndex3.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * -1.5 + lifeIndex2.size.width * 3, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)
```

I think this should position them just right beside each other.

> I think it is simpler for you to do this this way instead of creating a func and spawning three similar nodes